# Why my form go to the top of my screen when my UI freeze?

Tags: forms, delphi, freeze

I have a little issue with a form in a delphy XE2 application:

It's an old issue on this application and i have begin to work on it just since a little time.

When the user choose to launch the process with a button's event, my application launch a connexion with an OPCServer , an SQLServer and construct the form for a good following of data take on the tow servers.

The construction of my form involves a blockage of the interface (for approximately 15 sec) because of lot's of data which are necessary for make it.

When it freeze, if the user want drag the form, she go far away, and usually with the TMainMenu which go out of the screen. After that, it's impossible to use the application because we can't drag and we need to close and re-open.

In the old version, the form be already construct before the connexion. So the modification for a dynamic form isn't in link with this issue.

Life of my event :

```
    -Open connexion with OPC Server  
    -Open SQL Connexion  
    -Send SQL Command Text  
    -FieldByName('') for update my UI (Button.Caption// TPage.TStaticText.Caption // TPage.Label1.Caption)  
    -FieldByName('') for update an array of record  
    -Close SQL Connexion
    -Open SQL Connexion
    -Send SQL CommandText
    -FieldByName('') for update an other array of record  
    -Panel.Visible(false)  
    -TPage.Panel.Show;  
    -TPage.Panel.BringToFront;
```

So I haven't MainForm modification can change its position.

I'm a young developer, so I don't know why it moving and what I can make for repair that...

If you want a part of code, ask me what and i edit this, it's very long and i don't want spam answer.

Thank's for read.

Comment: The core of your problem is that you have lengtly process (form construction) which compleetly blocks the main thread so ypu application isn't posible to process normal Windows messages at the time. That is why when you move your application it doesen't propery upate its inteface. Now based on your description you already have this form constuction process split into multiple steps so you could call Application.ProcessMessages between them. This will force your application to update its UI part. You might also consider of showing a splash screen at start instead of half built form.

Comment: Thank's for resolve my issue =)

Comment: @SilverWarior You might want to post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @Andy_D I did now. I have taken some more time to epand my answe with what I hope is better exlanation of the problem. I also expanded it with adtitional informtion about the posible drawbacks and dangers of using Application.ProcessMessages method inproperly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of your problem is that you have a lengthy process (form construction) which completely blocks the main thread so your application isn't able to process normal Windows messages at the same time. That is why when you move your application it doesn't properly update its interface.

Now based on your description you already have this form construction process split into multiple steps so you could call `Application.ProcessMessages` between them.

This will force your application to update its UI part.

But beware calling `Application.ProcessMessages` often could hurt your application performance quite a bit. Why? It is usually a lengthy process because it forces your application to process all the messages that are in its queue.
Normally not all of these messages get processed as soon as they arrive. Windows groups them in the message queue by their priority list, making sure that high priority messages like `WM_PAINT` are processed as soon as possible while some other low priority messages like demand for application to respond to OS so that OS can see if the application is still working are mostly processed when application is idle or when they are in queue for certain amount of time.
So that is why `Application.ProcessMessages` can be so slow as it forces your application to process all messages regardless of their priority.

Also bear in mind that using `Application.ProcessMessages` can in certain scenarios actually become a bit dangerous.
Let me give you an example:
Lets say that clicking on a button starts a lengthy job which can take some time to finish. Now in order to allow your form to be updated you call `Application.ProcessMessages` in certain intervals. So far it is all good. But what happens if user clicks on that button again?
Since you are calling `Application.ProcessMessages` which forces your application to process all the messages and since clicking on button creates a MouseClick message which then fires buttons `OnClick` event which then executes the `OnClick` method that has been assigned to buttons `OnClick` event in the end this will cause the same method that was executed on first button click to be executed again.

So now you have this method partially done from first button click and same method executing again for second mouse click. Now the method that was executed from the second click will finish first and then the method that was started from first button click but was interrupted with `Application.ProcessMessages` handling the second button click will continue its execution to the end.
This all can lead to strange bugs which are hard to track, because you as a programmer normally don't predict that your end user might have clicked the button twice.

So to avoid this I strongly recommend you implement some safeguard mechanisms to prevent such scenarios by temporarily disabling a button for instance.
But the best solution is always to show your user that your application is working which in most cases will dissuade them from clicking the button again, but unfortunately not always.

You should also take a good care when dynamically constructing a form to enable the controls only after all of the controls have been successfully constructed. Failing to do so the user might click on one of your controls and that control could attempt to access some other control which hasn't yet been created at the time. The result hard to track bug which causes Access Violation.

You might also consider showing a splash screen at start instead of half built form. Why?
For once it is much nicer to see and it tells your users to wait a bit. And for second having main form hidden until it is fully created makes sure that user won't be doing any clicks on it prematurely.

Comment: Thank you for this good explain. I have resolve this issue.  
How to disable the form move ? I haven't find in the beginning of my search for this issue ...   
I'm going to follow your advise for the user impatience.
Thank's again =)

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is not at all a high priority message, on the contrary. It is created on the fly, along with `WM_TIMER` messages when the next message is requested from an empty message queue (i.e. after all other queued message have been handled). I did however not want to touch the content of your answer (only the spelling), so I suggest you rework that part yourself.